# MapRouteFinderResult serialization in Windows Phone c#

Tags: c#, serialization, navigation, windows-phone

I was wondering

1. If it is possible to serialize instance of MapRouteFinderResult class? Using DataContract lay in tatters - exceptions.
2. Or can I somehaw use pointers (save object as byte array, then set pointer to its begin)?

This is my class snippet

```
    [DataContract]
    public class Route
    {      
       [DataMember] public int Id {get; set;}
       [DataMember] public string name {get; set;}
       [DataMember] public MapRouteFinderResult routeResult  {get; set;}
       [DataMember] public DateTime creationDate  {get; set;}
    }
```

and this is serialization

```
private async Task serializeJsonAsync()
{
   try
   { 
       var jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Route));
       using (var stream = await  ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.
             OpenStreamForWriteAsync(JSON_FILENAME,
             CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting))
       {
             jsonSerializer.WriteObject(stream, route);
       }
       }catch(InvalidDataContractException iExc)
       {
            StatusTextBlock.Text = iExc.Message;
            return;
        }           
    }
```

Best regards,
Bubi